# How to convert a partitioned table into a non-partitioned table by using Oracle online redefinition with the object id kept

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate, oracle-cdc, dbms-redefinition

It is not difficult to convert a partitioned table into a non-partitioned table if we use a Oracle online redefinition and the object id of the source table is changed as a result of the operation because the interim table (non-partitioned) becomes an original table.

I realized the following fact in Oracle redefinition:

- To keep the object id of the source table, we should use an exchange partition of the redefinition, and its destination table is the same as the source table.

I wonder if there is any way to keep the object id in converting a partitioned table into a non-partitioned table with Oracle online redefinition. 
The reason is that at times it is not allowed to change the object id in CDC(GoldenGate/SharePlex) environment.

Comment: Are you talking about physical object id or object id? For partitioned table you have many partitions -> thus different physical object ids. So changing the table to non partitioned you would have just one identifier. How you want to keep that unchanged and still unpartitioning the table?